# Pushy push notification not working on specific devices

Tags: android, push-notification

Anyone using the Pushy API [http://pushy.me] ever encounter the following exception?

```
    Connect exception: me.pushy.sdk.exceptions.PushyNetworkException: class javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException
```

Comment: Pushy founder here. It appears that your device has rejected the HTTPS connection that our SDK is trying to establish with our servers. This could happen if someone on the network is performing a man-in-the-middle attack and presenting an untrusted certificate, if the device date is not synchronized, or if the device's certificate stores are for some reason incomplete / not up to date. 

Did this issue resolve itself after some time or are you still experiencing it?

Comment: Hi Elad, great API by the way. Yes it seems to have worked itself out. I do recall the device date being very incorrect. Are there any measures i can take to make sure this doesnt happen to my users? I only experienced this in sand-box

Comment: Unfortunately, this is simply how the HTTPS protocol works -- clients check the SSL certificate's expiration date and compare it to their local date and time to make sure the signed certificate has not expired. Since the client's configured date was way off (probably by a few years), the SSL certificate verification mechanism failed (as the device flagged the certificate as expired), causing communication with our servers to fail.

Comment: i see, thanks for the clarification.